# how to fix preg_match_all in php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

This the code I want to get text from

```
<tr><td valign="top"><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[PARENTDIR]"></td><td><a href="/administrator/components/com_simplephotogallery/x/">Parent Directory</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right">  - </td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
```

i used it like this:

`@preg_match_all("/<td><a href=\"(.*)\">/',$text,$ress);`

but the what I get is this

```
/administrator/components/com_simplephotogallery/x/">Parent Directory</a></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the greedy `(.*)`, use a negated character class `[^"]`:

```
preg_match_all('/<td><a href="([^"]+)">/', $text, $ress);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex instead

```
@preg_match_all("/<td><a href=\"(([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?)\">/',$text,$ress);
```

Comment: didn't work :/
thanks anyway.
i used a nother way
`foreach($ress[1] as $ress2 ){@ress2 = explod('\">', $ress2); $ress2 = $ress2[0];}`

Answer (score 0):

i just used

```
$a = explod('<a herf="',$text);
$a = explod('">',$a[1])
```

or anyone can just use DOMDocument class